# Flutter resize image to specific quality size

Tags: flutter, image

I try to resize an image in flutter. All the answers i found said I should use image_picker, flutter_image_compress or flutter_native_image package, but all of these specify a 0-100 scale of quality and not the exact size of the final image (for example 1MB). Is there any way to specify the real size of the file?

Comment: There is no way to know the real size of a jpeg until it's been compressed, but a 1080p 90% quality photo should be around 800KB.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, I think that size should be enough. I need only little logos of companies and the best I can do here is throw an error toast if the size is more than 1MB.